# What is the name of the office in an institution where graduates and alumni are helped with employment?

Tags: terminology, facilities-services

When I went to college, I remember there was an office that would help students, graduates and alumni get their first job.  What is that office called?

P.S. If you feel the English Stack Exchange more appropriate for this question, please move it there instead of down voting it.

Comment: Placement office?

Comment: The exact name will probably depend on the institution.  I just googled with the name of my son's college, and it gave me a short name (Career Center) and a fancy name (Center for Career and Professional Development).

Comment: It might not exist, at least formally. I routinely get requests for students (next to) graduate, even tough there are formal venues available.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In US universities, this office is commonly called ***Career Services*** or some variation on that, such as "career center", "career development", etc.

Answer (score 4):

On campus, my career/alumni connection office was called the career center. They help students with their cover letters, resumes, interviews, connections and job postings. I am not sure for other schools if they have an office just dedicated for jobs, like a head hunting agency ran by the school.

Answer (score 1):

It is called by various names - placement cell, placement center, career service, career center. There is no single name for it.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it tells me something I didn't know - placement cell. I Googled for it and found [Central Placement Cell, University of Delhi](http://placement.du.ac.in/).